# Is it possible to invoke OrchestrationTrigger or ActivityTrigger functions in a nuget package?(C#)

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-functions-core-tools

As the question has stated, I want to put orchestrator functions and activity functions into a nuget package for other projects to call. However, after testing locally, when I invoke an orchestrator function in another project (with another csproj file), I get this error:

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: 
FunctionName. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask: The 
function 'FunctionName' doesn't exist, is disabled, or is not an 
orchestrator function. Additional info: No orchestrator functions are
currently registered!
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load azure activity function from a referenced nuget package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55897954/how-to-load-azure-activity-function-from-a-referenced-nuget-package)

Comment: [Azure Durable Function Error "No activity functions are currently registered!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55056389/azure-durable-function-error-no-activity-functions-are-currently-registered)